# $I(u) = \int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{2}|\nabla u|^2+\frac{1}{2}|u|^2-fu dx$ has a minimum.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

> Let $I(u) = \int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{2}|\nabla u|^2+\frac{1}{2}|u|^2-fu
>  dx$, where $f\in L^2(\Omega), \Omega$ is a bounded open set in $R^n$.
>    Prove that $I(u)$ achieves its minimum over $v\in H^1(\Omega)$.

I can prove the $v\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ case: $I(u)$ is convex and we can prove that $I(u)$ has a local minimum by considering $F(t) = I(u+tv)$, and thus has a global minimum.

How about the $H^1(\Omega)$ case?

Comment: Same methods applies. After you take derivative, because $(\nabla u,\nabla v) + (u,v) = (f,v)$ has a unique solution for $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ too by Lax-Milgram thanks to the zero-th order term, not just $H^1_0(\Omega)$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the direct approach in the calculus of variations? You take a minimizing sequence, which is automatically bounded in $H^1$, and then extract a subsequence converging weakly in $H^1$ and strongly in $L^2$. Then the convexity of the integrand in $\nabla u$ gives you weak lower semicontinuity, so the limit is a minimizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the consequence of the *direct method* in the Calculus of Variation. For instance, you have 
$$
\int_\Omega fu \,dx\leq \frac12\int_\Omega f^2dx+\frac12\int_\Omega u^2dx \tag 1
$$
(think the algebra fact that $a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$)

Equation $(1)$ implies that 
$$
I(u)\geq \frac12\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2dx-\frac12\int_\Omega f^2dx\geq -\frac12\int_\Omega f^2dx>-\infty. \tag 2
$$

Hence, you may have a minimizing sequence $u_n$ in $H^1$ such that 
$$
I(u_n)\to \inf_{v\in H^1}I(v)=:m
$$
where the right hand side is not $-\infty$ because of $(2)$. Therefore, you have for $n$ large enough, 
$$
I(u_n)\leq m+1.
$$
Hence, you have $u_n$ is bounded in $H^1$ norm. The rest is as @Jeff's comment. you have weakly convergence in $H^1$ and by using strictly convexity, you done.